# Cannot find class in classpath - TestNG with Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I've never used TestNG before so I'm trying to understand it. I've installed TestNG and Built the path. I made a TestNG class with tests. But upon running as TestNG I get the error: `Cannot find class in classpath`

I am aware there are multiple questions out there with this issue but I've tried the answers given and none have worked.

I have tried this using JUnit and it ran successfully. Now I'm just trying to redo it using TestNG.

[Here is a screenshot of my project in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edf81.png)

```
public class TestSignInAndNotebook {

private WebDriver driver;
private Login login;
private Home home;
private CloudApp cloudApp;
private Notebook notebook;

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}

@Parameters({""})
@Test
public void f() {
    /* My test code */
}


@AfterTest
public void afterTest() {
    driver.quit();
}

}
```

If you need anymore information let me know.

Comment: Can you check from which folder the TestNG is starting. You can check this from your "Run Configuration" I believe .

Comment: How are you running your test case? Using TestNG suite file through Eclipse or running individually

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - Under Run Configurations it shows that it's running in the project called Wolfram, which is the correct project. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @KaarthickRamaMoorthy - I'm running using the TestNG suite through Eclipse.

Comment: @Alex - Have you tried running the class TestSignInAndNotebook individually? Was that working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try adding your folder Tests under the build path . Looks like it not added there and hence, is unable to recognise the class.
It should be like Wolfram/Tests under your Source

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I believe that the Tests folder is now under the Build Path (I could be wrong though). Unfortunately I'm still getting the error. I have updated my post and I have included my test class code and an update image of my project, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ah. I'm dumb. I had an annotation `@Parameters({""})`. But I didn't have anything in the quotes. I removed the annotation and it works like a charm. I have a feeling that all these answers also helped though. Thanks to all!